# Create two boot options for the same distro but with post run options

Tags: linux, boot, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian.

I installed Kodi (with autorun) but I'd like to install RetroPie into Raspbian also.

I'd like to have several grub options: one with Kodi in autorun, another with RetroPie and maybe another with a navigator and I'd like to select it from the boot menu (it will be easier for my wife)

I don't want to have multiple distros.

Is it possible?